# Can't read property 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript

I am working on a college project that requires me to build a 2D game in javascript. A problem that I'm having at the moment is that it cannot read the 'addEventListener'. This error has caused my game to not work completely.

```
document.getElementById('restart').addEventListener('click', startGame);
```

Here is the full code that I have used. The error is down the very bottom.

```
(function()
{
//Define variables
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var player, score, stop, ticker;
var ground = [], water = [], enemies = [], environment = [];

//Platform variables
var platformHeight, platformLength, gapLength;
var platformWidth = 32;
var platformBase = canvas.height - platformWidth;
var platformSpacer = 64;

//Randomly generates a number
function random(low, high)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (high - low + 1) + low);
}

//Bounds a number
function bound(num, low, high)
{
    return Math.max(Math.min(num, high), low);
}

//Loads all of the assets
var assetLoader = (function()
{
    this.imgs = {
        'bg'            : 'Images/bg.png',
        'sky'           : 'Images/sky.png',
        'backdrop'      : 'Images/backdrop.png',
        'backdrop2'     : 'Images/backdrop_ground.png',
        'grass'         : 'Images/grass.png',
        'avatar_normal' : 'Images/normal_walk.png',
        'water'         : 'imgs/water.png',
        'grass1'        : 'imgs/grassMid1.png',
        'grass2'        : 'imgs/grassMid2.png',
        'bridge'        : 'imgs/bridge.png',
        'plant'         : 'imgs/plant.png',
        'bush1'         : 'imgs/bush1.png',
        'bush2'         : 'imgs/bush2.png',
        'cliff'         : 'imgs/grassCliffRight.png',
        'spikes'        : 'imgs/spikes.png',
        'box'           : 'imgs/boxCoin.png',
        'slime'         : 'imgs/slime.png'
    };

    var assetsLoaded = 0; //How many assets have been loaded
    var numImgs = Object.keys(this.imgs).length; //Total number of image assets
    this.totalAssest = numImgs; //Total number of assets

    function assetLoaded(dic, name)
    {
        if(this[dic][name].status !== 'loading')
        {
            return;
        }

        this[dic][name].status = 'loaded';
        assetsLoaded++;

        if(assetsLoaded === this.totalAssest && typeof this.finished === 'function')
        {
            this.finished();
        }
    }

    this.downloadAll = function()
    {
        var _this = this;
        var src;

        for (var img in this.imgs)
        {
            if (this.imgs.hasOwnProperty(img))
            {
                src = this.imgs[img];

                (function(_this, img)
                {
                    _this.imgs[img] = new Image();
                    _this.imgs[img].status = 'loading';
                    _this.imgs[img].name = img;
                    _this.imgs[img].onload = function() {assetLoaded.call(_this, 'imgs', img)};
                    _this.imgs[img].src = src;
                })(_this, img);
            }
        }
    }

    return{
        imgs: this.imgs,
        totalAssest: this.totalAssest,
        downloadAll: this.downloadAll
    };
})();

assetLoader.finished = function()
{
    startGame();
}

function SpriteSheet(path, frameWidth, frameHeight)
{
    this.image = new Image();
    this.frameWidth = frameWidth;
    this.frameHeight = frameHeight;

    var self = this;
    this.image.onload = function()
    {
        self.framesPerRow = Math.floor(self.image.width / self.frameWidth);
    };

    this.image.src = path;
}

function Animation(spritesheet, frameSpeed, startFrame, endFrame)
{

    var animationSequence = [];
    var currentFrame = 0;
    var counter = 0;

for (var frameNumber = startFrame; frameNumber <= endFrame; frameNumber++)
{
    animationSequence.push(frameNumber);
}

this.update = function()
{
    if (counter == (frameSpeed - 1))
    {
        currentFrame = (currentFrame + 1) % animationSequence.length;
    }
    counter = (counter + 1) % frameSpeed;
};

this.draw = function(x, y)
{
    var row = Math.floor(animationSequence[currentFrame] / spritesheet.framesPerRow);
    var col = Math.floor(animationSequence[currentFrame] % spritesheet.framesPerRow);

    ctx.drawImage
    (
        spritesheet.image,
        col * spritesheet.frameWidth, row * spritesheet.frameHeight,
        spritesheet.frameWidth, spritesheet.frameHeight,
        x, y,
        spritesheet.frameWidth, spritesheet.frameHeight);
    };
}

var background = (function()
{
    var sky   = {};
    var backdrop = {};
    var backdrop2 = {};

    this.draw = function()
    {
        ctx.drawImage(assetLoader.imgs.bg, 0, 0);

        sky.x -= sky.speed;
        backdrop.x -= backdrop.speed;
        backdrop2.x -= backdrop2.speed;

        ctx.drawImage(assetLoader.imgs.sky, sky.x, sky.y);
        ctx.drawImage(assetLoader.imgs.sky, sky.x + canvas.width, sky.y);

        ctx.drawImage(assetLoader.imgs.backdrop, backdrop.x, backdrop.y);
        ctx.drawImage(assetLoader.imgs.backdrop, backdrop.x + canvas.width, backdrop.y);

        ctx.drawImage(assetLoader.imgs.backdrop2, backdrop2.x, backdrop2.y);
        ctx.drawImage(assetLoader.imgs.backdrop2, backdrop2.x + canvas.width, backdrop2.y);

        if (sky.x + assetLoader.imgs.sky.width <= 0)
        {
            sky.x = 0;
        }
        if (backdrop.x + assetLoader.imgs.backdrop.width <= 0)
        {
            backdrop.x = 0;
        }
        if (backdrop2.x + assetLoader.imgs.backdrop2.width <= 0)
        {
            backdrop2.x = 0;
        }
    };

    this.reset = function()
    {
        sky.x = 0;
        sky.y = 0;
        sky.speed = 0.2;

        backdrop.x = 0;
        backdrop.y = 0;
        backdrop.speed = 0.4;

        backdrop2.x = 0;
        backdrop2.y = 0;
        backdrop2.speed = 0.6;
    }

    return{
        draw: this.draw,
        reset: this.reset
    };
})();

//A vector for 2D space
function Vector(x, y, dx, dy)
{
    // position
    this.x = x || 0;
    this.y = y || 0;
    // direction
    this.dx = dx || 0;
    this.dy = dy || 0;
}

//Advances the vector's position
Vector.prototype.advance = function()
{
    this.x += this.dx;
    this.y += this.dy;
};

//Gets the minimum distance between two vectors
Vector.prototype.minDist = function(vec)
{
    var minDist = Infinity;
    var max = Math.max(Math.abs(this.dx), Math.abs(this.dy),Math.abs(vec.dx), Math.abs(vec.dy));
    var slice   = 1 / max;

    var x, y, distSquared;

    // get the middle of each vector
    var vec1 = {}, vec2 = {};
    vec1.x = this.x + this.width/2;
    vec1.y = this.y + this.height/2;
    vec2.x = vec.x + vec.width/2;
    vec2.y = vec.y + vec.height/2;
    for(var percent = 0; percent < 1; percent += slice)
    {
        x = (vec1.x + this.dx * percent) - (vec2.x + vec.dx * percent);
        y = (vec1.y + this.dy * percent) - (vec2.y + vec.dy * percent);
        distSquared = x * x + y * y;

        minDist = Math.min(minDist, distSquared);
    }
    return Math.sqrt(minDist);
};

//The player object
var player = (function(player)
{
    //Player properties
    player.width = 60;
    player.height = 96;
    player.speed = 6;

    //Jumping
    player.gravity = 1;
    player.dy = 0;
    player.jumpDy = -10;
    player.isFalling = false;
    player.isJumping = false;

    //Spritesheets
    player.sheet = new SpriteSheet('Images/normal_walk.png', player.width, player.height);
    player.walkAnim = new Animation(player.sheet, 4, 0, 15);
    player.jumpAnim = new Animation(player.sheet, 4, 15, 15);
    player.fallAnim = new Animation(player.sheet, 4, 11, 11);
    player.anim = player.walkAnim;

    Vector.call(player, 0, 0, 0, player.dy);

    var jumpCounter = 0;

    player.update = function()
    {
        //Jump if not currently jumping or falling
        if(KEY_STATUS.space && player.dy === 0 && !player.isJumping)
        {
            player.isJumping = true;
            player.dy = player.jumpDy;
            jumpCounter = 12;
        }

        //Jump higher if the spacebar is continually pressed
        if(KEY_STATUS.space && jumpCounter)
        {
            player.dy = player.jumpDy;
        }

        jumpCounter = Math.max(jumpCounter - 1, 0);

        this.advance();

        //Gravity
        if(player.isFalling || player.isJumping)
        {
            player.dy += player.gravity;
        }

        //Falling Animation
        if(player.dy > 0)
        {
            player.anim = player.fallAnim;
        }
        // change animation is jumping
        else if(player.dy < 0)
        {
            player.anim = player.jumpAnim;
        }
        else
        {
            player.anim = player.walkAnim;
        }

        player.anim.update();
    };

    //Draw the player's current position
    player.draw = function()
    {
        player.anim.draw(player.x, player.y);
    };

    //Resets the player's position
    player.reset = function()
    {
        player.x = 64;
        player.y = 250;
    };

    return player;
})(Object.create(Vector.prototype));

//Sprites
function Sprite(x, y, type)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = platformWidth;
    this.height = platformWidth;
    this.type = type;
    Vector.call(this, x, y, 0, 0);

    //Updating the sprites
    this.update = function()
    {
        this.dx = -player.speed;
        this.advancer();
    }

    //Drawing the sprites
    this.draw = function()
    {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5);
        ctx.drawImage(assetLoader.imgs[this.type], this.x, this.y);
        ctx.restore();
    }
}
Sprite.prototype = Object.create(Vector.prototype);

//Platforms
function getType()
{
    var type;
    switch(platformHeight)
    {
        case 0:
        case 1:
            type = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'grass1' : 'grass2';
            break;
        case 2:
            type = 'grass';
            break;
        case 3:
            type = 'bridge';
            break;
        case 4:
            type = 'box';
            break;
    }
    if (platformLength === 1 && platformHeight < 3 && rand(0, 3) === 0)
    {
        type = 'cliff';
    }

    return type;
}

//Update and draw all ground positions
function updateGround()
{
    //Animate ground
    player.isFalling = true;
    for(var i = 0; i < ground.length; i++)
    {
        ground[i].update();
        ground[i].draw();

        //Stop the player going through the platforms when landing
        var angle;
        if(player.minDist(ground[i]) <= player.height/2 + platformWidth/2 && (angle = Math.atan2(player.y - ground[i].y, player.x - ground[i].x) * 180/Math.PI) > -130 &&angle < -50)
        {
            player.isJumping = false;
            player.isFalling = false;
            player.y = ground[i].y - player.height + 5;
            player.dy = 0;
        }
    }

    //Remove the ground that has gone off screen
    if(ground[0] && ground[0].x < -platformWidth)
    {
        ground.splice(0, 1);
    }
}

//Update and draw all water positions
function updateWater()
{
    //Animate water
    for(var i = 0; i < water.length; i++)
    {
        water[i].update();
        water[i].draw();
    }

    //Remove water that has gone off screen
    if (water[0] && water[0].x < -platformWidth)
    {
        var w = water.splice(0, 1)[0];
        w.x = water[water.length-1].x + platformWidth;
        water.push(w);
    }
}

//Update and draw all environment positions
function updateEnvironment()
{
    //Animate environment
    for(var i = 0; i < environment.length; i++)
    {
        environment[i].update();
        environment[i].draw();
    }

    //R emove environment that have gone off screen
    if(environment[0] && environment[0].x < -platformWidth)
    {
        environment.splice(0, 1);
    }
}

//Update and draw all enemies position. Also check for collision against the player.
function updateEnemies()
{
    //Animate enemies
    for(var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++)
    {
        enemies[i].update();
        enemies[i].draw();

        //Player ran into enemy
        if(player.minDist(enemies[i]) <= player.width - platformWidth/2)
        {
            gameOver();
        }
    }

    //Remove enemies that have gone off screen
    if(enemies[0] && enemies[0].x < -platformWidth)
    {
        enemies.splice(0, 1);
    }
}

//Update and draw the players position
function updatePlayer()
{
    player.update();
    player.draw();

    //Game over
    if(player.y + player.height >= canvas.height)
    {
        gameOver();
    }
}

//Spawn new sprites off screen
function spawnSprites()
{
    //Increase score
    score++;

    //First create a gap
    if(gapLength > 0)
    {
        gapLength--;
    }
    //Then create the ground
    else if(platformLength > 0)
    {
        var type = getType();

        ground.push(new Sprite(
            canvas.width + platformWidth % player.speed,
            platformBase - platformHeight * platformSpacer,
            type
        ));
        platformLength--;

        //Add random environment sprites
        spawnEnvironmentSprites();

        //Add random enemies
        spawnEnemySprites();
    }
    //Start over
    else
    {
        //Increase gap length every speed increase of 4
        gapLength = rand(player.speed - 2, player.speed);
        // only allow a ground to increase by 1
        platformHeight = bound(rand(0, platformHeight + rand(0, 2)), 0, 4);
        platformLength = rand(Math.floor(player.speed/2), player.speed * 4);
    }
}

//Spawn new environment sprites off screen
function spawnEnvironmentSprites()
{
    if(score > 40 && rand(0, 20) === 0 && platformHeight < 3)
    {
        if (Math.random() > 0.5)
        {
            environment.push(new Sprite(canvas.width + platformWidth % player.speed, platformBase - platformHeight * platformSpacer - platformWidth, 'plant'));
        }
        else if(platformLength > 2)
        {
            environment.push(new Sprite(canvas.width + platformWidth % player.speed, platformBase - platformHeight * platformSpacer - platformWidth, 'bush1'));
            environment.push(new Sprite(canvas.width + platformWidth % player.speed + platformWidth, platformBase - platformHeight * platformSpacer - platformWidth, 'bush2'));
        }
    }
}

//Spawn new enemy sprites off screen
function spawnEnemySprites()
{
    if(score > 100 && Math.random() > 0.96 && enemies.length < 3 && platformLength > 5 && (enemies.length ? canvas.width - enemies[enemies.length-1].x >= platformWidth * 3 || canvas.width - enemies[enemies.length-1].x < platformWidth : true))
    {
        enemies.push(new Sprite(canvas.width + platformWidth % player.speed, platformBase - platformHeight * platformSpacer - platformWidth, Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'spikes' : 'slime'));
    }
}

//Game Loop
function animate()
{
    if(!stop)
    {
        requestAnimFrame(animate);
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        background.draw();

        //Update entities
        updateWater();
        updateEnvironment();
        updatePlayer();
        updateGround();
        updateEnemies();

        //Draw the score
        ctx.fillText('Score: ' + score + 'm', canvas.width - 140, 30);

        //Spawn a new Sprite
        if(ticker % Math.floor(platformWidth / player.speed) === 0)
        {
            spawnSprites();
        }

        //Increase player's speed only when player is jumping
        if(ticker > (Math.floor(platformWidth / player.speed) * player.speed * 20) && player.dy !== 0)
        {
            player.speed = bound(++player.speed, 0, 15);
            player.walkAnim.frameSpeed = Math.floor(platformWidth / player.speed) - 1;

            //Reset ticker
            ticker = 0;

            //Spawn a platform to fill in gap created by increasing player speed
            if(gapLength === 0)
            {
                var type = getType();
                ground.push(new Sprite(canvas.width + platformWidth % player.speed, platformBase - platformHeight * platformSpacer, type));
                platformLength--;
            }
        }

        ticker++;
    }
}

//Spacebar events
var KEY_CODES = {
    32: 'space'
};
var KEY_STATUS = {};
for(var code in KEY_CODES)
{
    if(KEY_CODES.hasOwnProperty(code))
    {
        KEY_STATUS[KEY_CODES[code]] = false;
    }
}
document.onkeydown - function(e)
{
    var keyCode = (e.keyCode) ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
    if(KEY_CODES[keyCode])
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        KEY_STATUS[KEY_CODES[keyCode]] = true;
    }
};
document.onkeydown - function(e)
{
    var keyCode = (e.keyCode) ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
    if(KEY_CODES[keyCode])
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        KEY_STATUS[KEY_CODES[keyCode]] = false;
    }
};

//Request Animation Polyfill
var requestAnimFrame = (function()
{
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function(callback, element)
    {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();

//Start the game and resets all variables and entities, spawn ground and water.
function startGame()
{
    document.getElementById('game-over').style.display = 'none';
    ground = [];
    water = [];
    environment = [];
    enemies = [];
    player.reset();
    ticker = 0;
    stop = false;
    score = 0;
    platformHeight = 2;
    platformLength = 15;
    gapLength = 0;

    ctx.font = '16px arial, sans-serif';

    for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        ground.push(new Sprite(i * (platformWidth-3), platformBase - platformHeight * platformSpacer, 'grass'));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < canvas.width / 32 + 2; i++)
    {
        water.push(new Sprite(i * platformWidth, platformBase, 'water'));
    }

    background.reset();
    animate();
}

//End the game and restart
function gameOver()
{
    stop = true;
    document.getElementById('game-over').style.display = 'block';
}

document.getElementById('restart').addEventListener('click', startGame);

assetLoader.downloadAll();
})();
```

Comment: Are you sure there's an element with the id `restart` in your HTML?

Comment: If you want us to help you, we need to be able to debug your code. And to be able to debug your code, we need your HTML. Therefore, please provide us [**a Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/) with the necessary JS code and HTML code to allows us to reproduce your issue!

Comment: Another issue could depend on when you load your script. You should be sure that the page is loaded to access the DOM elements. So, if you're sure your HTML contains the element with the id 'restart', you should check if you load the code in the right time, by placing the 'script' tag as the last element of the body.

Comment: Here's the HTML code and yes I do have a class called 'restart'. https://jsfiddle.net/h7ga4h61/6/